# Entity Framework cons of managing many to many relationship manually.

Tags: c#

I need a many-many relationship with a relationship attribute. From what I have read, the only way to do that in Entity Framework is to maintain one hidden Join table (created by Entity Framework) and one other Entity with the attribute, that links to the other two Entities.

Is there any significant drawback to manually managing the relationship? I would like to get rid of the navigation properties altogether, and query the relationship Entity for that information.

Comment: that's how you handle many-to-many relationships outside of the Entity Framework, its not a unique implementation

Comment: Sure, but I was trying to find out if there any kind of pitfalls to watch out for, specifically in EF. Why do people recommend using the other approach?